# PHP Mail not sending to email but no errors

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

when check the email track delievery section in cpanel it shows error message

> ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:128 CV=yes: SMTP error from remote mail
>   server after end of data: 550-5.7.1 [128.140.217.225 1] Our system has
>   detected an unusual rate of\n550-5.7.1 unsolicited mail originating
>   from your IP address. To protect our\n550-5.7.1 users from spam, mail
>   sent from your IP address has been blocked.\n550-5.7.1 Please
>   visit\n550-5.7.1 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=UnsolicitedIPError
>   to review our\n550 5.7.1 Bulk Email Senders Guidelines.
>   p6si713946edi.553 - gsmtp

don't know how to fix this.please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> mail sent from your IP address has been blocked.

They have blocked you out.
Try to contact support to fix it.